# How to make a Google Fusion Table private and use it with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-fusion-tables

I have recently create a fusion table and I'm able to work with it through javascript and php, but if I change the permission to private I am no more able to interact with it.
What can I do to keep it private and work with it? What authentication I must use?

Comment: You'll need [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de#clientside) (Note: FusionTablesLayer are not accessible for private tables)

Comment: I _think_ a [Google Maps for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) license might let you keep your data private but display a map.